# R: proto serialization/deserialization to list

Tags: r, mongodb, serialization, deserialization, proto

I'd like to be able to store some simple [`proto`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/proto/index.html) objects in a persistent store ([MongoDB](http://mongodb.org)) where their properties can be manipulated by code from other programming languages. By simple I mean that they will not refer to other proto objects. Their properties will be common R types: lists, vectors, etc. Further, each object can have a factory method that creates it given a list with its property values. Therefore the MongoDB-to-proto path seems straightforward.

I don't understand `proto`'s internals and R environment chaining well-enough to know whether there is a simple and robust way to get all the proto object's properties as an R list. Can this be done automatically or should I be thinking about all proto objects implementing something like a `to_list()` method?

Some example code using `testthat` and a new MongoDB driver API I am developing about the behavior I'd like to see here:

```
test_that("proto persistence", {
  Person <- proto(
    ..Name = 'PersonFactory',
    has_tag = function(., tag) { 
     tag %in% .$tags 
    },
    new = function(., name, tags=c()) {
     .$proto(..Name='Person', name=name, tags=tags)
    } 
  )

  p1 <- Person$new(name='bob', tags=c('friend', 'coworker'))

  coll <- test_db()$collection('test') 
  coll$store('bob', p1)

  result <- coll$find_one(id='bob')
  expect_true(is.list(result))
  expect_true(is.list(result$proto))
  expect_equal(result$proto$name, 'bob')
  expect_equal(result$proto$tags, c('friend', 'coworker'))

  p2 <- coll$load('bob')
  expect_equal(p2$name, 'bob')
  expect_equal(p2$tags, c('friend', 'coworker'))
  expect_true(p2$has_tag('friend'))
})
```

Comment: @G.Grothendieck , proto's maintainer, often comes by SO. I would suggest you post some code in the meantime.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks for the suggestion. I am looking for logical serialization of the data to an R list that can be persisted as well as inspected/modified in MongoDB. I have changed the title of the question and the description to make this clear. Is there a good way to just grab the data from a proto object as well as all its parents, etc?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I added code about the expectations I'd like to satisfy here. If I hook up the object creation via a `$new` factory method it seems that this should work as the parents should get correctly hooked up there, right?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck the general idea works perfectly. In my case, I prefer using an explicit constructor method via a factory proto. https://gist.github.com/3431917 If you add your previous comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn `p1` from the question into a list. `L1` :

```
L1 <- as.list(p1)
```

and to turn it back into a proto object, `p1a`, whose parent is `Person` :

```
p1a <- as.proto(L1, parent = Person)
```

You can then build whatever structure you want around these basics.